# jQuery exeption on click inside container

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?
I'm new to jQuery and can't figure it out.

I have this code that on click is showing a drop down cart that closes when you click outside the container. `#show-header-cart`

inside the container is a close tag `.is-close` that is not working.
Can i add a exception that if the .is-close tag  inside the container `#show-header-cart` is clicked that it also closes the cart?

[Screenshot of cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZNuk.jpg)

```
    const $menu = jQuery('#show-header-cart');

    jQuery(document).mouseup(e => {
       if (!$menu.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
       && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            $menu.removeClass('header-cart-active');
            $menu.css('opacity', 0);
        }
     });
```

```
    jQuery('#header-cart-icon').on('click', () => {
        $menu.addClass('header-cart-active');
        $menu.css('opacity', 1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing you can add click event on the `.is-close'

```
$(".is-close").click(function() {
      $menu.removeClass('header-cart-active');
      $menu.css('opacity', 0);
});
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply.

unfortunately this is not working.

Everything thats inside `#show-header-cart` doesn't respond to click, removeClass etc.